# Using MockitoSugar of scalatestplus-play deprecated

Tags: playframework, mockito, playframework-2.0, scalatest, playframework-2.2

I'm using `"scalatestplus-play" % "5.1.0"`, and I'm trying to bring `MockitoSugar` to my class like I did in earlier projects:

```
class MyTestSpec extends AnyFreeSpec with MockitoSugar
```

so I can use the `mock[MyClass]` function and now it docent exists, can't find in the documentation something else.

in my earlier projects I used `"scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.3"`, I'm sure there is a different way now but can't find what it is

Comment: John, I contributed to `scalatestplus-play`, such that it should be available in the next release. https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/pull/296

Comment: @TomerShetah awesome!! well done my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option you have, is to use [scalatestplus-mockito](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-mockito), where you can find `MockitoSugar`, as you are used to.

From [ScalaTest](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects) Testing with mock objects:

> You can use any Java mocking framework with ScalaTest, or ScalaMock, a Scala mocking alternative. ScalaTest provides just enough syntax sugar for the three most popular Java mocking frameworks—JMock, EasyMock, and Mockito—to remove boilerplate and clarify the client code.

Another option, as said in the attached link, there are 4 libraries that can be used. The easiest one in my opinion is `ScalaMock`. To use it you need to extend  `MockFactory`.

It should be imported from:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
```

The difference is that `"scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.3"` depends on [ScalaTest](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/blob/4.0.3/build.sbt#L33) version 3.0.8 which still had `MockitoSugar`. `"scalatestplus-play" % "5.1.0"` depends on ScalaTest [3.1.1](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/blob/5.1.0/build.sbt#L30) which no longer has it.