# Unit test a controller with AssetsFinder dependency in Play Framework

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, scalatest

I have a controller that looks like:

```
class LoginController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)
                               (implicit ec: ExecutionContext, assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
```

I would like to write a unit test for that controller, but I need something to mock the *assetsFinder* dependency:

```
class LoginControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerSuite { 
  "something to test" should {
    "behave as expected" in {
      val controller = new LoginController(stubControllerComponents())(???)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I mock that dependency?

Comment: Leo, does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
class LoginControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Results with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {
    "something to test" should {
        "behave as expected" in {
            val mockControllerComponents = mock[ControllerComponents]
            implicit val mockAssetsFinder = mock[AssetsFinder]
            implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
            val controller = new LoginController(mockControllerComponents)
            // asserts here
        }
    }
}
```

`MockitoSugar` was part of `scalatest` up to version 3.0.8 . If you are using a newer version, you need to import:

```
"org.scalatestplus" %% "mockito-3-2" % "3.1.1.0",
```

or any other version that works for you from [scalatestplus-mockito](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-mockito). If you are using `scalatestplus-play`m please read [Using MockitoSugar of scalatestplus-play deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64883780/2359227).